# Exclude collision listener to one object

Tags: lua, coronasdk

on line 6 of the code below i have added a `Runtime:addEventListener("collision", onCollision)` but it is interacting with everything with a body, how to exclude collision listener to one object in this in this case 'BCloud1.png'

```
function getRandomStar()
    local temp = starTable[math.random(1, #starTable)] -- Get a random star from starTable
    local randomStar = display.newImage(temp.imgpath) -- Set image path for object

    if ( temp.imgpath == "BCloud1.png" ) then
    physics.addBody( randomStar, "static", { density=.1, bounce=.1, friction=.2, radius=45 } )
    Runtime:addEventListener("collision", onCollision)
    temp.imgpath = "BCloud"..tostring(math.random(1, 3))..".png";
    end

    if ( temp.imgpath == "BCloud2.png" ) then
    temp.imgpath = "BCloud"..tostring(math.random(1, 3))..".png";
    physics.addBody( randomStar, "static", { density=.1, bounce=.1, friction=.2, radius=45 } )  
    end

    if ( temp.imgpath == "BCloud3.png" ) then
    temp.imgpath = "BCloud"..tostring(math.random(1, 3))..".png";
    physics.addBody( randomStar, "static", { density=.1, bounce=.1, friction=.2, radius=45 } )  
    end

    randomStar.myName = "star" -- Set the name of the object to star
    randomStar.movementSpeed = temp.movementSpeed; -- Set how fast the object will move
    randomStar.x = math.random(-30, _W);    
    randomStar.y = -35;
    randomStar.rotation = math.random(0,20) -- Rotate the object

    starMove = transition.to(randomStar, {
        time=randomStar.movementSpeed, 
        y=500,
        onComplete = function(self) self.parent:remove(self); self = nil; 
        end
        }) -- Move the star
end--END getRandomStar()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use

```
Runtime:addEventListener("collision", onCollision)
```

and control what collides with what, then use collision filters. The are much easier then they look.

This is the tutorial I used when learning about them.

[Collision Filters](https://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2010/10/25/collision-filters-helper-chart)